# What are "mutually orthotomic circles" in (19th century) English?

Tags: geometry, curves

I'm currently reading some Clifford's papers, where I read "if three circles are mutually orthotomic [...]" (cf. http://www.archive.org/stream/mathematicalque05unkngoog#page/n150/mode/2up), but I can't find a definition of "orthotomic circles" on the Web. Moreover, almost all links point to 19th century papers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"orthotomic" means "perpendicularly cut" just from Greek vocabulary. And from the picture I believe that it means that at each intersection point of any two circles, their tangent lines at that point are perpendicular. The two circles on the right don't quite meet that, but 4 points of intersection seem to meet that requirement really well, and I wouldn't expect those without computers to get diagrams exactly right.

Comment: I believe you are right, thank you!